# Array having multiple inner objects,extract an deeper inner objects as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, javascript-objects

What I had

```
{
     "1zkhj45kjb3h3jj27777fjd": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "abc@gmail.com",name:"abc"   } },
     "1zkhj45kjb3h898fj7fjddk": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "dumy@gmail.com",name:"dumy" } } 
}
```

What I've done

```
const snapshot = snap.val()
const items = Object.values(snapshot)
```

now `items` looks like

```
[
    {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "abc@gmail.com",name:"abc"   } },
    {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "dumy@gmail.com",name:"dumy" } } 
]
```

But I want

```
[
    { email: "abc@gmail.com",name:"abc"   } ,
    { email: "dumy@gmail.com",name:"dumy" } 
]
```

I have tried all other stretegies like `Object.keys`, `Object.enteries`.
if I again call `object.values` it gives same result.

How to do it javascript ?
I'm newbie to react native and javascript.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with `Object.values()` to get an array of the inner objects:

```js
const items = {
     "1zkhj45kjb3h3jj27777fjd": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "abc@gmail.com",name:"abc"   } },
     "1zkhj45kjb3h898fj7fjddk": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "dumy@gmail.com",name:"dumy" } } 
}

const result = Object.values(items).flatMap(Object.values)
  
console.log(result)
```

If `Array.flatMap()` is not supported, use `Array.map()` instead. However, the result would be an array of arrays, so you'll need to flatten it. You can flatten it by spreading the array of arrays into `Array.concat()`:

```js
const items = {
     "1zkhj45kjb3h3jj27777fjd": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "abc@gmail.com",name:"abc"   } },
     "1zkhj45kjb3h898fj7fjddk": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "dumy@gmail.com",name:"dumy" } } 
}

const result = [].concat(...Object.values(items).map(Object.values))
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: great answer @Ori Drori  but will you please tell me that why this is giving error in react native (undefiled is not an function)

Comment: It's not supported by react native out of the box, and you'll need to use a [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/Array.prototype.flatMap).

Comment: I've added another solution that flattens the array using `Array.concat()`.

Comment: Great  Man and bundle of thanks for saving my day @Ori Drori  can you  please some give explaination to this. it will be realy helpful for me for next time

Comment: how  [].concat(...Object.values(items).map(Object.values))  this line is working ?

Comment: Am i right or wrong ?  if i do const result =  Object.values(snapshot).map(Object.values)

Comment: What would be output ?

Comment: Because Object.values()` returns an array, the result would be an array of arrays - `[[{}], [{}]]`, where each sub array contains an object.

Comment: Cool, i'll get it by time   Thanks for explanation Stay blessed

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) twice with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const data = {
 "1zkhj45kjb3h3jj27777fjd": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "abc@gmail.com",name:"abc"   } },
 "1zkhj45kjb3h898fj7fjddk": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "dumy@gmail.com",name:"dumy" } } 
};

const result = Object.values(data).map(Object.values).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately it didn't worked in react native

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.values()` to get the nested objects as an array, then use `.map()` to get the value of the `-L7hgtdyYUYY56` of each of them.

```js
const snapshot = {
 "1zkhj45kjb3h3jj27777fjd": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "abc@gmail.com",name:"abc"   } },
 "1zkhj45kjb3h898fj7fjddk": {"-L7hgtdyYUYY56":{ email: "dumy@gmail.com",name:"dumy" } } 
};

var result = Object.values(snapshot).map(e => e["-L7hgtdyYUYY56"]);
console.log(result);
```

This assumes that the nested objects just have one property and they're all the same property name, as in your example. If it's more dynamic, the other answers that flatten the objects are more appropriate.

Comment: @Bammer thanks for answer but what if i don't know -L7hgtdyYUYY56 this values each time.  all answers snippets are working fine but in react native it is not working

Comment: If you don't know the property name, use the other answers.